# Remove Phone Number from order success email in Magento

Tags: php, email, magento, magento-1.8

we want to remove phone number from both shipping address and billing address in order success email. We found `sendNewOrderEmail` function under `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/order.php` but not sure how to remove phone number from billing and shipping addresses.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution, need to override the following customer configuration file

> /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml

delete `{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}` near line 560 under `<address_templates>`